# Unplug or switch off AC outlet when laptop is not in use?

Tags: battery-life, ac-adapter

I just replaced the battery of my laptop, Inspiron 15 7000 7567, it was damaged (swelling) and now it works fine.

I used to have my laptop connected all the time with the AC adapter, and the AC adapter was connected to an AC power outlet with switches. So I only switched it ON and OFF when the battery was full or needed charging.

I been reading some pages about battery life improvement and all of them say that it is recommended to unplug the laptop when it reaches 100% of charge or it is not being used. But no one says anything about switches in the AC outlet.

My question is, does unplugging the laptop have the same effect as turning OFF the switch in the AC power outlet? Or should I unplug the AC adapter from the laptop for better performance/battery life?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the switch is faulty in some way, it should be the same. You can verify this by having the computer powered on, then switch the switch to OFF and see if the laptop sees this as not charging or charging at a low rate. The first should be happening. If the second, then you have a faulty switch.

Answer (score 1):

> does unplugging the laptop have the same effect as turning OFF the
> switch in the AC power outlet?

Yes, it is the same.

If you wish to have the AC Adapter plugged in and ON, then you need Battery Threshold Management as a Laptop APP and in your BIOS (UEFI) as well.

If you have that, you can reset the Battery and set the charge to 80% (start charging again at 75%) and leave it like that.

I have my own Laptop set like I suggested and it is always ON, and the Battery shows 80%, plugged in, and not charging.

Works great.